# Orchestration bettween wildfly and mysql database

Tags: mysql, docker, wildfly

I'm using docker-compose to launch 1 container with jboss wildfly 10 and another with mysql.
If the mysql container takes some time to launch, and in this case the wildfly gives the following error:

```
12:42:35,612 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
...
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: db
...
```

and the wilfly is started (with errors):

```
12:42:40,346 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started (with errors) in 14048ms - Started 492 of 818 services (57 services failed or missing dependencies, 383 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

When the mysql container is later started, it does not affect wildfly.

My docker-compose.yml is:

```
api:
    image: eu.gcr.io/jornaloficial-1265/pt.globaleda.jo-api
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: service
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: service
      MYSQL_DATABASE: api
      MYSQL_HOST: db
    networks:
      - back
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.11
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - back
```

My Dockerfile for api service:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:10.0.0.Final
MAINTAINER José Meireles "zmeireles@gmail.com"

ADD mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main/
ADD module.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main/
ADD keycloak-wildfly-adapter-dist-1.9.1.Final.tar.gz /opt/jboss/wildfly/
ADD standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
ADD ato_template.odt /opt/jboss/
RUN mkdir /opt/jboss/pdf-src
RUN mkdir /opt/jboss/pdf-dest
ADD pdf-src /opt/jboss/pdf-src/
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
ADD api.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

And the configuration of the datasource in my standalone.xml:

```
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/mydb" pool-name="my_pool"
                    enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://${env.MYSQL_HOST}/${env.MYSQL_DATABASE}?autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useSSL=false</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>${env.MYSQL_USER}</user-name>
                        <password>${env.MYSQL_PASSWORD}</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
```

To reproduce the problem:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d api
sleep 10
docker-compose up -d db
docker-compose logs
```

It it possible for Wildfly to detect when the database is ready, or as a alternative fail and exit if the datasource subsystem exits? In this later case I can use a script that launches the wildfly in a loop

Answer (score 0):

WildFly's datasource configuration offers the option to validate connections.  In the management GUI select Configuration -> Subsystems -> Datasources -> Non-XA -> ProcessEngine -> View.  Select "Validation" from the tabs on the screen.

Click the "Edit" link.  In the "Check Valid Sql" box, enter the following:

SELECT 1

I also check the "Background Validation" box.  Save the configuration (you may have to disable the datasource first and go through this process again and/or you may have to reload the server).

This configuration performs a constant check of the datasource connection.

Another thing you can do is set the timeout in Camunda (I think) for its datasource, though I can't say how that's done.  I think it's pretty tolerant.

Comment: Already tried the check valid sql and background validadion in the standalone.xml configuration.

Comment: The problem is on startup. The exception "java.net.UnknownHostException: db" appears and the datasource subsystem fails